# Node typescript error: Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have added typescript to a node/express project. Though I have specified `"noImplicitAny": false` in my tsconfig.json file, typescript goes mad because I don't type an error in a promise in my index.ts file.

Here is the code:

```js
mongoose
  .set()
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB)
  .then(() => server.listen(process.env.PORT))
  .catch((err) => console.log("error", err));
  
  // ts output: Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

My folder structure is:

- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- src

  - index.ts

The tsconfig.json is:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "mails/*": ["src/mails/*"],
      "models/*": ["src/models/*"],
      "routers/*": ["src/routers/*"],
      "routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
      "utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in vscode, but maybe your IDE doesn't accept the tsconfig.json because its misconfigurated."exclude" doesn't belong into "compilerOptions", it needs to be an entry in the outer object: {"compilerOptions": {....}, exclude: [...]}.

Comment: Well played! It was the solution!